# PHP:preg_replace function

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing, preg-replace

```
$text = "
<tag>
<html>
HTML
</html>
</tag>
";
```

I want to replace all the text present inside the tags with htmlspecialchars(). I tried this:

```
$regex = '/<tag>(.*?)<\/tag>/s';
$code = preg_replace($regex,htmlspecialchars($regex),$text);
```

But it doesn't work.
I am getting the output as htmlspecialchars of the regex pattern. I want to replace it with htmlspecialchars of the data matching with the regex pattern.
what should i do?

Comment: Why do you want to do that ? The whole idea behind htmlspecialchars is to encode the tags (for example `<script></script>` to make it unharmful.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: @StephenTG I want to display the html code which is in the <tag> tag as text and not execute it.

Comment: So you basically want to run htmlspecialchars on anything in a <tag> block?

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML.  Use a proper HTML parsing module.** You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're replacing the match with the pattern itself, you're not using the back-references and the `e`-flag, but in this case, [`preg_replace_callback`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) would be the way to go:

```
$code = preg_replace_callback($regex,'htmlspecialchars',$text);
```

This will pass the mathces groups to `htmlspecialchars`, and use its return value as replacement. The groups might be an array, in which case, you can try either:

```
function replaceCallback($matches)
{
    if (is_array($matches))
    {
        $matches = implode ('', array_slice($matches, 1));//first element is full string
    }
    return htmlspecialchars($matches);
}
```

Or, if your PHP version permits it:

```
preg_replace_callback($expr, function($matches)
{
    $return = '';
    for ($i=1, $j = count($matches); $i<$j;$i++)
    {//loop like this, skips first index, and allows for any number of groups
        $return .= htmlspecialchars($matches[$i]);
    }
    return $return;
}, $text);
```

Try any of the above, until you find simething that works... incidentally, if all you want to remove is `<tag>` and `</tag>`, why not go for the *much* faster:

```
echo htmlspecialchars(str_replace(array('<tag>','</tag>'), '', $text));
```

That's just keeping it simple, and it'll almost certainly be faster, too.

### [See the quickest, easiest way in action here](http://codepad.org/qLH8vJWv)

Comment: I want to replace the string with the htmlspecialchars of that string.

Comment: @user1763032: Yes, I deleted, and corrected my previous answer. I've fixed that now

Comment: I get an error "htmlspecialchars expects parameter 1 to be a string . array given..."

Comment: @user1763032: Ok, fixed that, too, and added a _Super_-easy and fast alternative approach, too. I'd use that one if I were you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to isolate the actual contents as defined by your pattern, you could use `preg_match($regex,$text,$hits);`. This will give you an array of hits those bits that were between the paratheses in the pattern, starting at $hits[1], $hits[0] contains the whole matched string). You can then start manipulating these found matches, possibly using `htmlspecialchars` ... and combine them again into `$code`.

Comment: can you tell me how to do that? i am new to php